# More than One Role to a User

Tags: moodle

Hello Guys I am facing difficulties with the Users Role allotment in Moodle . As I have made a Main Administrator, Batch Facilitator , Teacher and Students . I want to allot Batch Facilitator with two roles as Manager and Course Creator. But when ever I allot Roles I see only one option from a drop down menu what to do I am really confused.

Comment: Is there any moodle developer right now to suggest me assigning the roles properly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot associate two roles to the same user in the same context. The alternative is to create an additional role with all the permissions you want these users to have.